# How do I pull robust standard errors from logit in R?

Tags: r, mlogit, robustness

I have conducted a logit regression in R using the code below (top). Now I am trying to obtain the robust standard errors for the exact same regression. I am using the code below (bottom) for that as well, but the significance varies considerably afterwards.

I am wondering if the code I am using is appropriate, and if it is not whether that might be related to why some variables are significant before the robust SE estimations but not afterwards. Thank you.

```
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
setwd("C:/...")
mydata <- read.csv(file="sextest.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings=c(""))
sapply(mydata,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
sapply(mydata, function(x) length(unique(x)))
model <- glm(LCC ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=mydata)

require(foreign)
require(sandwich)
fitglm <- glm(LCC ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=mydata)
cov.m1 <- vcovHC(fitglm, type = "HC0")
std.err <- sqrt(diag(cov.m1))
q.val <- qnorm(0.975)
r.est <- cbind(Estimate = coef(fitglm), "Robust SE" = std.err , z = (coef(fitglm)/std.err) , "Pr(>|z|) "= 2 * pnorm(abs(coef(fitglm)/std.err), lower.tail = FALSE) , LL = coef(fitglm) - q.val  * std.err , UL = coef(fitglm) + q.val  * std.err)
r.est
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a sandwich estimator would be the correct approach to get the robust standard errors of a logit model and your code looks correct.

Comparing your normal and robust standard errors side by side, you will most likely see that your robust standard errors are somewhat larger. Since your estimates are unaffected, it would mean that some parameters will go from significant to insignificant. This is common and essentially what you want. You calculate robust standard errors because you believe that the normal ones are incorrect because of, for example, heteroskedasticity, which may lead you to wrongly conclude that a parameter is significant when it is not.